# Is a select with MAX() and GROUP BY() efficient or will it read all rows

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I have a created cassandra table  like so:

```
create table messages
    (user_id int, peer_id int, send_on timestamp, message text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, peer_id, send_on))
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (peer_id ASC, send_on DESC);
```

and populated with data.

I want to query the latest message for each peer_id for a given user and what I came up with was:

```
select peer_id, max(send_on), message 
  from messages 
  where user_id = 1 group by peer_id;
```

I was wondering if this is going to read ALL the messages and just extract the latest or it is smart enough to only pick up the latest message.

The reason I asking is because populate the table with the following values:

```
1, 1, now(), hello 1
1, 1, now(), hello 2
1, 1, now(), hello 3
1, 2, now(), hello 4
1, 2, now(), hello 5
1, 2, now(), hello 6
...
1, 3, now(), hello 9
```

And when I run the query I see the expected result:

```
select peer_id, max(send_on), message from messages where user_id = 1 group by peer_id;

 peer_id | system.max(send_on)             | message
---------+---------------------------------+---------
       1 | 2019-04-13 19:20:48.567000+0000 | hello 3
       2 | 2019-04-13 19:21:07.929000+0000 | hello 6
       3 | 2019-04-13 19:21:22.081000+0000 | hello 9

(3 rows)
```

However with tracing on, I see:

```
 activity                                                                                                                      | timestamp                  | source    | source_elapsed | client
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------
                                                                                                            Execute CQL3 query | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.948000 | 127.0.0.1 |              0 | 127.0.0.1
 Parsing select peer_id, max(send_on), message from messages where user_id = 1 group by peer_id; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.956000 | 127.0.0.1 |           8812 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                             Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.957000 | 127.0.0.1 |          10234 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                    Executing single-partition query on messages [ReadStage-2] | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.962000 | 127.0.0.1 |          14757 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                    Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.962000 | 127.0.0.1 |          14961 | 127.0.0.1
                                       Skipped 0/0 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-2] | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.962000 | 127.0.0.1 |          15211 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                       Merged data from memtables and 0 sstables [ReadStage-2] | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.963000 | 127.0.0.1 |          15665 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                          Read 9 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-2] | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.963000 | 127.0.0.1 |          15817 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                              Request complete | 2019-04-13 19:24:54.964448 | 127.0.0.1 |          16448 | 127.0.0.1
```

So it seems like it reads ALL 9 rows. Is there a way to optimize this? Maybe change my schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options I can think of would be for you to make another table that acts as an index to the max record for each userID and peerID. Those two fields would make up your Partition key and then would contain the rest of the data you need to find the max record in your messages table for that userID and peerID. The data would get upserted anytime you put data onto it so you'd always just write the most recent message to that table and it would always be the max. The other thing you could do is just store the last message there altogether and then you don't have to reference your messages table there at all for the actual data. Same partition key that I mentioned before, just write the actual message there too.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will have to go with another table. That’s the Cassandra way anyway I guess

Answer (score 0):

So here's a thought; change your partition key to `user_id` and `peer_id`, and then you can use the `PER PARTITION LIMIT` construct.  That will only read a single row back (per partition), and then you also won't have to use `MAX` as the first row will be the most-recent due to `CLUSTERING ORDER BY (send_on DESC)`:

```
> CREATE TABLE messages
    (user_id int, peer_id int, send_on timestamp, message text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, peer_id), send_on))
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (send_on DESC);

> SELECT peer_id, send_on, message
          FROM messages
          WHERE user_id = 1 AND peer_id=1
          PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;

 peer_id | send_on                         | message
---------+---------------------------------+---------
       1 | 2019-04-15 15:21:40.350000+0000 | hello 3

(1 rows)

> SELECT peer_id, send_on, message
          FROM messages PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;

 peer_id | send_on                         | message
---------+---------------------------------+---------
       3 | 2019-04-15 15:21:40.387000+0000 | hello 9
       2 | 2019-04-15 15:21:40.365000+0000 | hello 6
       1 | 2019-04-15 15:21:40.350000+0000 | hello 3

(3 rows)
```

Note: The last query is a multi-key query done for demonstration purposes only, and obviously not something to be done in a large, production cluster.